# How to insert a blank value instead of NULL in Columns other than String datatype in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, null

I have a create statement like

> CREATE TABLE temp_tbl (EmpId String,Salary int);

I would like to insert an employee id and a blank value into table.

So What I have done is

1. insert overwrite table temp_tbl select '013' as EmpId,'' as Salary from tbl;

> ```
> hive> select * from temp_tbl;
> OK
> 013     NULL
> ```

But expected result is

```
hive> select * from temp_tbl;
OK
013     NULL ---> Blank instead of NULL
```

2. Also tried with "". Still I get it as NULL instead of blank

3.Tried to create table with serialization property

```
CREATE TABLE temp_tbl (EmpId String,Salary int) TBLPROPERTIES ('serialization.null.format' = '');
```

That too didn't change NULL value to blank.

What can be the workaround for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use Case while selecting the data.

```
Select 
(CASE 
       WHEN columnName is null THEN ''
       ELSE columnName 
END) as 'Result' from temp_tbl;
```

Comment: My requirement is to insert blank value to salary column with out any case condition

Comment: @UnmeshaSreeVeni You cannot insert blank value to Integer column because Integer itself cannot be empty, only String can be empty, Empty string is a normal string value like any other string.. Integer can be NULL or valid number

Answer (score 0):

All types except strings/varchar/char and some complex types like array, in Hive cannot be blank, only NULL is possible. Empty string `''` is quite normal value of type String. You can produce empty array() as well (Array with zero size).

**As a workaround**, you can use some predefined values which are not normally in your data to represent some special numeric values, like -99999. Alternatively you can store your numeric values in a String column, in such case you will be able to have empty values in it. But **it's not possible to assign (cast) empty strings to numeric types, because such empty value is not allowed.**

If you try to assign empty string to numeric column or cast to numeric type, the result will be the same as if you are converting non-numeric string to numeric - NULL (in Hive if not possible to cast, it returns NULL) or get [java.lang.NumberFormatException](http://www.java67.com/2016/10/10-reasons-of-javalangnumberformatexception-in-java-solution.html) in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that datatype Int can be either NULL or integer , I'd think of how to work around the problem.

1. I have the impression that 0 can do the job. Why can it not?
2. If 1 is not ideal, why not create a new temp_employees_with_no_salary table?
3. If 2 is not ideal, can you afford to change the datatype of temp_tbl.Salary from Int to String, then use CAST(Salary AS INT) to work with it?